# Differences from Up and back button

Tags: android

In an android app I have activities A, B and C.

In the initial flow I have user seeing activity A, touching a button leads to activity B. Touching a button there leads to activity C.

An alternative way to open the app is double clicking on the wallpaper (the app is a wallpaper BTW). This prepares an intent for A with extras, which are read during activity creation. Before A is shown it prepares and launches B and C using startActivities.

When triggering the alternative flow I can see C successfully, and pressing up leads me to B. Pressing up again leads me to A. That is the expected behaviour from the users perspective, and that's what I want to happen. However if instead of pressing UP I use the back button to go C -> B -> A, before A is shown the logic is triggered and B -> C is reopened again.

According to my code I'd expect to see what I see when I press back, which is undesirable but understandable.

a) why is the up button behaving differently from the back in this case?

b) what is the cleanest way to know if I'm reaching A from outside the app or pressing either back or up, so I can use a slighly different logic?

BTW All 3 activities have their own fragments, and the project uses dagger and butterknife.

EDIT: I also noticed that if I'm on C and I press up twice I'm again in A (which has no up button), but if I press back I see A for a second time, as if my stack has 2 copies of A. The expected behaviour instead would be leaving the app. Is this related to `android:launchMode`?

Answer (score 0):

An UP Button will lead you to your parent activity if you have defined it in your manifest file as below-

```
</activity>
        <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
        android:parentActivityName=".FirstActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.android.home.app.FirstActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Otherwise it will act like a normal back press, It means it will finish the current activity only.

For Your case, check if you are finishing activity B when you are moving from B to C. Because if you are getting activity A on back press then there is only one activity A in stack. Activity B is defined as parent activity for C and activity A is defined as parent activity for B that is why you are getting activity A on double UP button press.

Answer (score -1):

After tinkering with launch mode, this is what is finally working for me:

- Declare A, B and C with `android:launchMode="singleTop"` made the back and up buttons behave in the same manner (note that B needs to keep its intent all the times)
- When A is launched and detects extras it will create a new intent to A without extras and with `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`. This will make the stack contain a new fresh copy of A that doesn't redirect to B or C

Note that this was ok because A didn't need any extras for its own views. If it were the case I'd have to pass dedicated extras to my new A intent, to avoid ambiguity for the cases where it was opening for the first time or when going back from C.

The case of changing intents for singleTop activities seem to not have a clean answer, according to this thread: [How to properly clear intent data from singleTop Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719113/how-to-properly-clear-intent-data-from-singletop-activity)